# Deleting a non-existent record from an Access database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I use the below code to DELETE a row in a table when a specific string(entity) is found. It works fine but it fails if the "entity" does not exist in the database.

```
using (OleDbConnection thisConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionname))
{
    string deletequery = " DELETE FROM SFModelOutputVariables WHERE [Entity] = '" + ENTITY + "'";  
    OleDbCommand myAccessCommandDelete = new OleDbCommand(deletequery, thisConnection);
    try
    {
        thisConnection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + "\n" + "-Error found while " + "connecting to Access Database");
        return;
    }

    myAccessCommandDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
    thisConnection.Close();
}
```

I get an error for the line `myAccessCommandDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();` when data for the selected entity does not exist in the table.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Yes LarsTech is correct. This code is very dodgy, i could loose my job for writing code like this. You need to use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the entity exsists. Run the delete if the entity exsist but if it doesnt exsist possibly return a 404 to the user or display an appropriate message.

```
    using (OleDbConnection thisConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionname))
    {

 string cmdStr = "Select count(*) from SFModelOutputVariables WHERE [Entity] = '" + ENTITY + "'"; 

 OleDbCommand cmd = new      OleDbCommand(cmdStr, thisConnection);

   int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   if(count == 0)
   {
         MessageBox.Show("Sorry no entity was found :-(");
            return;
   }

   // write your code for removing things here....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use executescalar method, its giving row count of table. if its > 0 you can perform delete operations.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
ExecuteScalar method sample